# How do I use the @odata.nextlink parameter returned in the Reporting API response in .net C# application

Tags: c#, .net, odata

I am retrieving data from an odata service. The response contains a link for loading more data i.e. odata.nextLink which I need to retrieve to load more data(odata.nextLink). How do I do this using C# code? The server's response is something like this:

```
{
  "odata.metadata":"http://localhost:60497/odata/$metadata#tables","value":[
    {"id":001,"name":"abc" }

      .
      .
  ],
"odata.nextLink":"http://localhost:60497/odata/tables?$skip=10"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The presence of the odata.nextLink element is used to indicate that there are more results available.
If you simply want to fetch all results then you would keep fetching additional results from each successive nextLink URI until you receive a response that does not contain a nextLink element.

In the most simple case you could simply have a while loop, however in most situations if a query is returning a large set of results you would want to retrieve some and then offer the user the means to request more rows.

In C# you might be using the [OData Client library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.OData.Client/) from Microsoft which allows you to perform LINQ queries on OData services.

Microsoft's documentation has a comprehensive example at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/odata/client/pagination

Comment: Completely agree with this, but if i am not using Odata Client Library to get the api response instead I am using HTTP Client , how could I achieve the same. so coming back to my question how can i get the values of @Odata.nextlink attribute to a local string variable in c#.

Answer (score 1):

Create a class for the Json Object which is returned, Like this

```
public class Value
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        [JsonProperty("odata.metadata")]
        public string OdataMetadata { get; set; }
        public List<Value> value { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("odata.nextLink")]
        public string OdataNextLink { get; set; }
    }
```

Try to deserialize the Json object returned, here data is going to be the Json Object in String Format.

```
var RootObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(data);
```

From this RootObj, you will be able to get the OdataNextLink value and other values you need,  which you can store in your local variable.

Let me know if you have more questions on this.